# are there major changes to the registry between windows 7 and windows 10?

Tags: registry, windows-10-desktop

I'm reading Windows Registry Forensics by Harlan Carvey and not finding the Registry entries he references (I'm using regedit to try to follow his examples.) I see that his book references Windows 7, not Windows 10, and I'm wondering if there was a major overhaul of the Registry between these releases of Windows.

Comment: Answer: yes.  Although, your question is not the type of question for this forum.  More appropriate would be a a specific question about a difference and it's impact for an application you are developing.